# Storyboard with multiple UITabBarControllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have the following storyboard setup:

[image: Screenshot of storyboard]

I would expect, that the two `UITabBarControllers` (blue and red) connecter to the orange `UINavigationController` and each display the different view controller and the "shared" one. However when running the app only one of the `UITabBarControllers` (the red one) has both view controllers. The other `UITabBarController` (blue) only has one item in the tab bar, which is not the orange one.

I have given all the different view controllers unique ID's but it doesn't change anything.

I could just duplicate the orange view controller but that would sort of be inconvenient, as everything is the same and it would clutter the storyboard.

Is there a way to accomplish the desired result with out cloning the orange view controller (ie. through code somehow)?

Comment: I believe that when you connect the orange view controller with segue in the interface builder(design time) thats when it takes the tab bar from the one connected to it. therefore it only takes one of them. I don't know if thats the one connected first or at last. I don't see a solution for that.

Comment: It is not connected as a transition segue it is connected as a relationship segue (view controllers) of either one of the tab bar controllers

Comment: please add code when you perform segue wit identifier.

Comment: I just managed to do it as you want simply.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I will list the steps as we just started a new project:

1. Here, we have only the starting view controller.
2. select it, click Editor on menu bar Embed in navigator controller.
3. add a view controller from the right-bottom window.
4. embed in with the new view controller, two tab bars.
5. connect the starting view controller with both of the tab bars with a push segues(using buttons).
6. customise both of the tab bars.
7. test by clicking the two buttons.

I hope this is clear and helpful.
[image]

[image]

This happened in the design time the later connected tab bar replaces some property of the previously connected tab bar. I don't think this can be fixed (at least the way we are doing it). if that property could be set to both tab bars the interface builder would do it for us. I don't think that could be solved.

Comment: The is a weird result. I will attach screenshots

Comment: the orange view controller behave normally with the tab bar connected at last in design time. and buggy with tab bar connected at first.

Comment: I am getting the same results, thats why i asked :)

Comment: this happened in the design time the later connected tab bar replaces some property of the previously connected tab bar. I don't this can be fixed. if that property could be set to both tab bars the interface builder would do it for us. I don't think that could be solved.